# Using listings' escapebegin/escapeend with short commands

Tags: xetex, pdftex, listings

I'm building `beamer` slides with code set using `listings` and I want to draw arrows to parts of the code. To achieve that I have a zero width command that defines a named PGF coordinate (given as the argument), here called `libraryCommand`.

Now the problem: I want to have a pretty syntax, so I use `escapeinside`, which *should* allow me to write `QhereW` to create a coordinate called `here`. Instead of writing the full command.

The argument that's passed to `libraryCommand` has to be wrapped between two commands, I use the environment for that. It works outside the `lstlisting`. But inside, I get `Missing \endcsname inserted:  \end{^lstlisting}`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    % escapeinside={Q}{W}, % uncommenting this fails.
    escapebegin=\begin{wrapThat},
    escapeend=\end{wrapThat}
}
\newcommand{\libraryCommand}[1]{((#1))}
\newenvironment{wrapThat}{\wrapToEnd}{}
\long\def\wrapToEnd#1\end{\libraryCommand{#1}\end}
\begin{document}
  foo \begin{wrapThat}bar\end{wrapThat} baz
  \begin{lstlisting}
    foo QbarW baz
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

So, how could I get this to work? I can't see what special thing they do in the DTX...

Comment: About the `wrapThat` environment: Have a look at the `environ` package which allows the definition of (pseudo-)environments which collect the body and provide it as `\BODY` in the end-code. Also using a plainTeX style envrionment like `\wrap ... \endwrap` would be better.

Comment: Ah, forgot about that... But it doesn't work either: Using `\NewEnviron{wrapThat}{\libraryCommand{\BODY}}` it fails with `\begin{wrapThat} ended by \end{lstlisting}.` (but works outside `lstlisting`)

Comment: And with plainTeX environments like `\def\wrapThat#1\endWrapThat{\libraryCommand{#1}}` it fails with `File ended while scanning use of \wrapThat`.

Comment: @pascal: It seems that the endmarker is not inserted directly by `listings`. Rather the `Q` and `W` are probably active and expand to the `escapebegin` and `escapeend` codes. Therefore `\wrapThat` never finds `\endWrapThat` because `W` isn't expanded yet. With your initial code the `\end` it finds would be then the `\end{lstlisting}`!

Comment: yes, looks like it. Wouldn't it be possible to find `W` in the `escapebegin` command to get the tokens between `Q...W`, then restore `W` so it can be expanded to `escapeend`? (Just using `W` doesn't work though, I guess there's some catcode magic at work?)

Comment: @pascal: Yes, you most likely need to use `\begingroup\catcode`W=\active\gdef\wrapThat#1W{\libraryCommand{#1}}\endgroup`. Then `escapeend` can actually be empty. Or you simply add `W` after `\libraryCommand{#1}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And with plainTeX environments like `\def\wrapThat#1\endWrapThat{\libraryCommand{#1}}` it fails with `File ended while scanning use of \wrapThat`.

It seems that the endmarker is not inserted directly by `listings`. Rather the `Q` and `W` are probably active and expand to the `escapebegin` and `escapeend` codes. Therefore `\wrapThat` never finds `\endWrapThat` because `W` isn't expanded yet. With your initial code the `\end` it finds would be then the `\end{lstlisting}`!

You need to define a macro which scannes for an active `W` instead:

```
\begingroup
\catcode`W=\active
\gdef\wrapThat#1W{\libraryCommand{#1}}%
\endgroup
```

If you need the endmarker for any other `escapeend` code, then you can readd the active `W` after your command:

```
\gdef\wrapThat#1W{\libraryCommand{#1}W}%
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution from Martin Scharrer's comment:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  escapeinside={Q}{W},
  escapebegin=\wrapThat,
  escapeend=%
}
\newcommand{\libraryCommand}[1]{((#1))}
\begingroup%
  \catcode`W=\active%
  \gdef\wrapThat#1W{\libraryCommand{#1}W}%
\endgroup
\begin{document}
  \begin{lstlisting}
    foo QbarW baz
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```